# Same code or not for UserHostAddress?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Are the two methods below identical?

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
```

and

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems so. According to [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) the

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
```

maps to

```
// System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequest
public override string GetRemoteAddress()
{
    return this.GetServerVariable("REMOTE_ADDR");
}
```

So in my opinion, it is the same.

Comment: As long as HttpContext.Current.Request actually is an ISAPIWorkerRequest. I would argue, that you cannot ensure that they are identical; especially since GetRemoteAddress() is virtual.

Comment: @ChristopheDebove ILSpy is always a handy tool to look into the sources of the .NET Framework.